# file path is not getting assigned to variable in cmd

Tags: batch-file, cmd, command-line

In cmd I want to assign the file path of a file say `'test.txt'` to a variable name filePath, complete file location is not know, it is know only up to certain folder so I am using `dir /b /a /s "test.txt"`. I am using below syntax :

```
set filePath=C:\Users\kadamr\AppData\Local\Test>dir /b /a /s "test.txt"
```

When I echo the value of filePath I get the syntax instead of filePath.

i.e : `C:\Users\kadamr\AppData\Local\Test>dir /b /a /s "test.txt"`

What I am missing ?

Comment: in batch you can't do it this way. You need a [for /f](https://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) loop to capture the output of a command. Did you really try to include the prompt `C:\Users\kadamr\AppData\Local\Test>`? What gave you that idea?

Comment: I am new at command line. dir /b /a /s "test.txt" gave the path for file in command line. I wanted to store this output so that I can use it when needed. So tried the thing.

Comment: Visit the link, I gave you. It explains how to store it.

Comment: What about most simple `for /F "delims=" %%I in ('dir "%LocalAppData%\test.txt" /A-D /B /S 2^>nul') do set "filePath=%%~dpI"`? Please note that the file path is assigned with backslash at end to the environment variable `filePath` on at least one file with name `test.txt` found in local application data directory or any of its subdirectories. Run in a command prompt window `cmd /?`, `dir /?` and `for /?` and read carefully the output help for each command from top to bottom. Note: __FOR__ runs the command line between `'` with `%ComSpec% /c` and the command line appended in background.

Answer (score 0):

If this is always under the users's home directory, use the USERPROFILE variable as the base directory from which to search. Why did you use `/a` when no attribute is specified? Also, keep in mind that more than one `test.txt` file may exist somewhere under the base directory.

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "EXITCODE=1"
SET "BASEDIR=%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Test"
FOR /F "delims=" %%A IN ('DIR /S /B "%BASEDIR%\test.txt" 2^>NUL') DO (
    ECHO COMMAND: CALL doit.exe "%%~A"
    IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (SET "EXITCODE=%ERRORLEVEL%" & GOTO TheEnd)
    SET "EXITCODE=0"
)
:TheEnd
EXIT /B %EXITCODE%
```